# C++ function with char** parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I have some problems at understanding char pointers.
Let's say there is the following method declaration (sorry but I don't have the implementation of the method, I hope it's enough to explain my problem):

```cpp
short GetInfo(char **param1, char **param2);
```

I tried to call it 2 different ways:

```cpp
// 1. When I call it this way it works
char param1_val[20];
char *param1_ptr = param1_val;

char param2_val[20];
char *param2_ptr = param2_val;

GetInfo(&param1_ptr, &param2_ptr);

// 2. When I call it that way I get an 'access violation exception'
char *param1_array[20];
char *param2_array[20];

GetInfo(param1_array, param2_array);
```

I thought

```cpp
char param1_val[20];
char *param1_ptr = param1_val;
```

is the same as

```cpp
char *param1_array[20];
```

But it seems they are different.
Is there a way how I could get my second case work? Or did I mix things up and I have to do it like in case 1?

Comment: Pointers are a pain, and pointers to pointers double so. This is very much self-inflicted. That said, you should know what an array is, what a pointer is, and how they relate.

Comment: @MSalters: It's a given interface written by someone I can't ask any more. I know pointers are pain, especially for someone who is very new to C++. That's why I'm here at SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought
>
> `char param1_val[20];`
>
> `char *param1_ptr = param1_val;`
>
> is the same as
>
> `char *param1_array[20];`

They're not the same.

```
char param1_val[20];
char *param1_ptr = param1_val;
```

Declares an array of 20 chars `param1_val` and declares & assigns `param1_ptr` to the memory location of `param1_val[0]`, so `&param1_val[0]`.

```
char *param1_array[20];
```

Declares an array of 20 char pointers `param1_array` that still all point to garbage locations.

I'm assuming that `GetInfo` is dereferencing the pointers in your `param1_array` and that causes the access violation as trying to read from a random memory address is not something you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The probable reason for declaring `GetInfo` as a function taking a `char**` is that it *outputs* a `char*`, so it is probably expected to be used more like so:

```
//short GetInfo(char **param1, char **param2);
char *ptr1=nullptr;
char *ptr2=nullptr;
GetInfo(&ptr1,&ptr2);
if(ptr1)    
    std::cout<<*ptr1<<std::endl; 
//etc
```

To really understand pointers and arrays, find C documentation on the subject. In C++, they are backwards compatible with C. However, in C++ it is better to work at higher level, e.g. use STL instead of coding in C style.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have a look at.
I agree with you, the method wants to return a `char*`.
But if I initialize the parameters with `nullptr` they are still null after the method call.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't want to output a pointer after all. Could be just a needless indirection.